# Using the conjunction "as" to express similarity

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

Is the following sentence gramatically corrent?

> He has shown sufficient technical aptitude, **as has he** high motivation to complete the project earlier.

In this sentence what meant is that the person has shown both the technical aptitude and the high motivation.

I am not sure the *as - aux. verb. - subject* (e.g. *as has he*) construction is gramatically correct in such a context. And if it is, what are other conjunctions that could possibly replace it in this context without much changes to the rest of the sentence?

Comment: It's OK grammatically. The unusual thing about this comparative clause is the position of the subject, which here is located after the verb.  The effect of the inversion is to place a contrastive subject in end position, so "high motivation ..." contrasts with "sufficient technical aptitude". I don't think there's an alternative to "as" in this construction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As* with  subject auxiliary verb inversion is used to emphasize the clause.
you could also, quite simply, replace **as has he** with the preposition **with**, and without the comma.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! So, it is not an error to use this structure in the example sentence?

Comment: it's not a grammatical problem. it simply puts more attention to the fact that he is highly motivated in completing the project.
I think (just my opinion) that "with" is cleaner.